# Measuring distance from point to closest point feature in GDAL/OGR in same point shapefile?

Tags: python, ogr, python-2.7

I am tying to trying to get the closest point of every point in Python using GDAL module. But some how I did some mistakes.

Here is my sample code:

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import gdal


shpfile=r"P:\materials_python\All_GPS_apr17_may5_2016_Corrected_final\All_GPS_apr17Tomay5_2016_Corrected_final.shp"
driver=ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
PointsDs=driver.Open(shpfile)
layer=PointsDs.GetLayer()
counts=layer.GetFeatureCount()# get featurecount in gdal
print counts

geomAll=[]
for feature in layer:
    geom=feature.GetGeometryRef()
    print geom.ExportToWkt()
    geomAll.append(geom)
print geomAll[0]
for i in range(0,len(geomAll)):
    dist=min([x.Distance(geomAll[i+1])for x in geomAll])
    print geomAll[i].ExportToWkt()
```

But it is not showing any result after this line:

```
print geom.ExportToWkt()
```

I did not get also any error Message. I do not know what I did wrong.
Does anybody have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I can give you better and more efficient solution with numpy, scipy and ogr:

```
from osgeo import ogr
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
ds = ogr.Open(pathtofile)
layer = ds.GetLayer()
# get coordinates of points as 2d array
coords = np.array([(feature.GetGeometryRef().GetX(), feature.GetGeometryRef().GetY()) for feature in layer])
# calculate distance matrix between points
distances = cdist(coords, coords)
# sort distances to each point
sorted_distances = np.argsort(distances, axis=1)
# get 2nd column from sorted matrix (it contains 2nd closest points because 1st is always 0!!!)
closest_points = coords[sorted_distances[:,1]]
```

And now our `closest_points` you can interpret as `closest_points[0]` is the closest point to `coords[0]` etc.